# Second scenario doesn't run if first fails in selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, gherkin

I have a selenium test case with multiple scenario's. I have a problem if the first one fails it doesn't run the second scenario properly. It does show the error for the first one failing. The one following it will just show all green check marks without starting up the UI tests. In the example below Bob has an error (throws an exception), but Sandra has never even started up the browser and it still shows like she has passed.

```
Abstract Scenario: I should be able to login
Given I log in with user with the login '<username>'
And I give the password '<password>'
Then I am logged in

Example:
| username | password |
| Bob      | easyPassword|
| Sandra   | hardPassword |
```

Does anyone know how to make the second scenario show the proper results instead of showing it like it passed? It is important because it's helpful to know one which exact scenario the test has failed.

Comment: We will need to see the step definitions as well. The problem does not come from Gherkin, but your step definitions and how the web driver is initialized and managed throughout the test run.

Comment: The problem doesn't seem to be here anymore. There must be something wrong with the actual java code